# How to implement dynamic product price calculation on weight basis in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-prices, dynamic

I'm developing an eCommerce website in Magento for Silver business. the price of the product is should be in weight basis.

For example today I've added a 1000 rupees silver necklace of 10 grams to my website with the silver rate 40 rupees per gram, by next day silver rate maybe fluctuates and the price of the product needs to be change.

The final product price in the product/list page and cart page = ( today's silver rate x number of grams (1, 2, 3...etc) + making charges ).

Here Silver rate will be fluctuates depending on market rate. I'm new to magento, please guide me with valuable codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage weight wise product price in two ways in magento:

1. **By creating configurable product with weight variance**. For more information click  [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/)
2. **By adding custom option in a simple product**. For more information click [here](https://insync.co.in/how-to-create-custom-options-configurable-products-in-magento/)